# Build menu based on nutritional requirements

Tags: ruby, algorithm, knapsack-problem

I need to generate seven daily menus. A menu consists of breakfast, lunch, dinner and three snacks. I have a few hundred recipes taken from fatsecret.com. Each recipe contains nutritional information such as: calories, fat, sodium, fiber. Each daily menu is restricted to:

```
Calories: 1500
Sodium: 200g
Fiber: 32g
Fat: 30g
```

I'm calculating all possible combinations of breakfast, lunch, dinner, and snacks, then iterating through them and summing their nutritional information. As soon as I find seven combinations that meet the nutritional requirements, I stop. But I need a more efficient way.

I am thinking of a tree structure that backs up every time a bad menu choice is made and tries a different branch, but I'm stuck on this one. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There certainly are more sophisticated algorithms, but what happens if you try combinations uniformly at random until one succeeds?

Comment: I've tried selecting random combinations. I've found that because the nutritional requirements are quite strict that this is also very slow. I'm allowing nutrition values to be within 200 units of the requirements and still finding it slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can index the recipes in something like a [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) - this will allow you to efficiently eliminate recipes that cannot be combined with the current menu selection, and will allow you to apply heuristics to improve the chances of finding a valid combination (e.g. "dinner cannot account for more than 50% of the daily calories")

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest a couple of possible approaches.

**Sample Combinations**

The first approach, which is the easier to implement, would be to randomly select a recipe for each meal and total the ingredients.  Keep it if it satisfies the nutritional limits.  If you sample, say, a hundred million combinations, you may well get a few that qualify.  It's easy enough to try it.

**Use an Approach Inspired by Dynamic Programming**

I say "inspired by" dynamic programming ("DP") as I regard DP as solely an optimization technique.  There is no need for the reader to know about DP, but for those who do, the "stages" will be the meals and the "states" at each stage will be the combination of nutritional values provided by recipes for all meals up to and including the meal associated with the given stage.

For each dietary item, suppose we can round:

- calories to the nearest 20;
- sodium to the nearest 5 gms;
- fiber and fat each to the nearest gram.

Considering that the nutritional content will vary somewhat, this does not seem unreasonable.

This gives us 76*41*33*31 => 3,187,668 acceptable combinations of the four nutrients.

There are six meals, denoted `0` through `5`. For each possible recipe, we have a hash of quantities of the four nutritional component, such as:

```
{ calories: 460, sodium: 55, fibre: 4, fat: 6 }
```

Let `r[0]` be a hash with elements `k=>v`, where the keys are arrays `[calories, sodium, fibre, fat]`, one for each combination of:

- `calories`, between `0` and `1500`, in multiples of 20;
- `sodium`, between `0` and `200` in multiples of `5`;
- `fibre`, between `0` and `32`; and
- `fat`, between `0` and `30`.

For a given key `[calories, sodium, fibre, fat]`, the associated value is a set of recipes for meal `0` that provide that given combination of ingredients.

We simply go through all recipes that are available for meal zero.  If a given recipe corresponds to the nutritional content given by key `k`, we see if the associated value, `r[0][k]`, already contains a sufficient number of recipes (e.g, 7). If it does not, we add that recipe to the value (array).

Suppose now we have performed the computations I am about to describe for meals `0, 1, 2,..., i`. We will have computed `r[j]`, `0 <= j <= i`, where `r[j]`, is a hash whose keys are combinations of the four nutritional values and whose values are (*please read the following very carefully*) a set of recipes for all meals `0, 1, 2,..., i` that result in the nutritional values given by the key.

We now compute `r[j+1]` by performing the following steps.

For each key `k` in `r[j]`:

```
k = [calories, sodium, fibre, fat]
```

we consider each recipe for meal `j+1`, characterized by:

```
[r_calories, r_sodium, r_fibre, r_fat]
```

and compute

```
k' = [calories+r_calories, sodium+r_sodium, fibre+r_fibre, fat+r_fat]
```

If any of these four values exceeds the associated maximum daily limit, the recipe cannot be used for that particular key.  If the values are all within the limits, this will be a key of `r[j+1]`. The value of associated with that key, `r[j+1][k']` is the set of all recipes for all meals up to and including meal `j+1` that result in the nutritional values given by that key. If that value does not include a sufficient number (e.g.., at least `7`) of recipes for meal `j+1` (together with recipes for earlier meals), we add the recipe we have been considering, together with all the recipes given by `r[j][k]`.  We then repeat this for all possible recipes for meal i. When finished, we repeat these steps for each of the other keys in `r[i]` (of which there may be millions).

Note it would not actually be necessary to store all recipes for all meals up to and including meal `j+1` in the value (array) `r[j+1][k']`. Rather, we would just store the recipes for meal `j+1` and for each of those, a pointer to an associated key in `r[j]`.

Each `r[j]` will have at most 3,187,668 keys, but in fact the number would likely be considerably smaller. If there were, say, 100 possible recipes for each meal, we would have to perform at most 3187668 * 100 => 318,766,800 of these operations for each of the five meals after the first.  The important thing to note here is that the number of calculations increases (only) linearly with the number of meals. I would expect is would be manageable from a computational standpoint.

All values in `r[5]` represent sets of recipes for all six meals that satisfy the maxmimum daily nutritional values.  If no combinations are found, none exist.

Answer (score 0):

If the restrictions aren't too tight, then [Metropolis--Hastings sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm) may be of use. (Otherwise, you'll need Cary's dynamic program or perhaps integer programming.) The bias introduced by the sampling should push the menu toward feasibility while ensuring randomness.

Initialize the menu by choosing each course uniformly at random. Make the following step repeatedly until the menu is acceptable. Starting with the current menu, choose a course uniformly at random and a recipe uniformly at random, deriving a proposed menu by using that recipe for that course. Define the *score* of a menu to be as follows.

```
    max(calories - 1500, 0)     max(sodium - 200, 0)    max(32 - fiber, 0)    max(fat - 30, 0)
0.99                        0.95                     0.7                   0.7
```

(The bases of the exponents deserve some experimentation. I'm assuming that excess calories, sodium, and fat are bad, as is insufficient fiber.) Keep the proposed menu if and only if `rand` (uniform float in [0.0, 1.0)) is less than the score of the proposed menu divided by the score of the current menu.